# Flutter firebase collection snapshot pricing

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When i call `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('someName').snapshot`

Is that mean that it is 1 read for pricing, or if collection have 20 docs, its 20 reads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The billing unit is called a "**document** read" on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing). If you read 20 documents, you're charged for 20 document reads.